# How do I close COM1 after I left it open?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

I'm working in Visual Studio C#, and I opened up a serial port, but I didn't properly close it. Now I cannot run my program to try to close it. I know it was me that was using it, but somehow I've lost control of it..? Is there a way to close it otherwise?

I've tried exiting out of visual studio and it still says that my access is denied. I've unplugged and replugged in the actual object I'm using. My next step is to restart the computer, but I don't want to have to do that everytime I mess up (which is frequently!)

On a side-note, I'm working in a lab and do not have administrative access on this computer. Another note is that the error's text is "Access to the port 'COM1' is denied."

In response to those asking for code,.. comPort.Open(); What else are you looking for?

```
private void updateAccuSwayData() {
    Console.WriteLine("Update thread started...");
    comPort.Open();
    comPort.WriteLine("Q");
    Thread.Sleep(5);
    while (!cancelRequested) {
        //do stuff...
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Update thread halted.");
    comPort.WriteLine("R");
    comPort.Close();
}
```

In a nutshell, I ended my debugging session while it was in middle of something it seems. That's about all I know.

Comment: Please add the code you use to open and close it

Comment: Is this a real COM port, or a USB adapter?  Also, which version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: I am using a real COM port, and I'm using .net 4

Comment: That's not how it works, Windows will always close a port if you forget.  Maybe your program is still running?  Use Thread.IsBackground if you use threads.  Crappy USB drivers are a common scourge too.

Comment: @HansPassant: one possibility is the `vshost` instance may be stuck in the background with a reference to the COM port.

Comment: I've edited every piece of code I could find that opened and closed the port and put the closing in a finally block. So it seems that on the first instance when I start the program it says access is denied, but if I step over that, it then goes to port is already open when it tries again. I downloaded and tried a sample program to check to see if the port functions properly and it has no problems at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll likely need to reboot to clear this up, although one approach would be to use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and search for a handle to `\Device\Serial0`. You can then see if closing this handle works, it may not however.

To work to keep  this from happening in the future, you need to put the `comPort.Close()` call in a `finally`-block:

```
try
{
    comPort.Open();
    // ...
}
finally
{
    // Almost always ensures the COM port will be cleaned up,
    // however, the MSDN remarks state that the port may not
    // be closed immediately.
    comPort.Close();
}
```